# How to stop enemy from moving diagonally?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed a tutorial about an enemy detecting your player when you are near their radius. It worked, but I wanted my enemy to move only horizontal and vertical. What should I put or change on my code?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3f;
    private Transform target;

    private void Update()
    {

        if(target != null)
        {

            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
        }


    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            target = other.transform;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            target = null;
        }
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to calculate new Vector based on the direction of our target and modify that vector to not move diognally, something like following would work

```
private Vector2 newPosition;

private void Awake() {
    newPosition = transform.position;
}

private void Update() {
    if (target != null) {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float threshold = .1f;

        // Only calculate new position if we are under the "threshold"
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, newPosition) < threshold) {
            newPosition = target.position - transform.position;

            if (Mathf.Abs(newPosition.x) > Mathf.Abs(newPosition.y)) {
                newPosition.x = target.position.x;
                newPosition.y = transform.position.y;
            }
            else {
                newPosition.x = transform.position.x;
                newPosition.y = target.position.y;
            }
        }

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, newPosition, step);
    }
}
```

In here I am only calculating `newPosition` if the distance between current position and `newPosition` is less then some `threshold`, after that I am getting new direction vector which points toward our `target`, and then modifying that vector based on the biggest component of that vector.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Also, thank you for the explanation. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check which axis has the smaller delta and move in this axis first, then do the other one

```
private void Update()
{
    if(target == null) return;
    
    Vector2 endPosition = target.position;
    Vector2 delta = target.position - transform.position;

    if(Mathf.Abs(delta.x) > Mathf.Abs(delta.y))
    {
        // Y is the smaller delta => move only in Y
        // => keep your current X
        endPosition.x = transform.position.x;
    }
    else
    {
        // X is the smaller delta => move only in X
        // => keep your current Y
        endPosition.y = transform.position.y;
    }

    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    
}
```